# Text is shown differently in browser and in page source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a web project in Visual Studio 2012 (ASP.NET MVC 4).

In the file `_layout.cshmtl` I have the following:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

In `HomeController`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cửa hàng giầy dép thời trang"; 
    return View();
}
```

When I run the website, the browser displays "Cửa hàng giầy dép thời trang".

But when I view the page source it shows `"Cửa h&#224;ng giầy d&#233;p thời trang".`.

Why is this difference?

[image]

Comment: Why do you care what the source code shows??

Comment: What you are seeing is the [ASII representation](http://www.lookuptables.com/) of the character. The browser takes this and converts it to the necessary display character. for example sometimes you will see `&nbsp;` or `&amp;` which simply represent a space ` ` and ampersand `&`

Comment: "Why do you care what the source code shows??" =>Thanks for answer, I worry it affects the seo